# How do i load a bitmap in Direct2D containing an alpha channel

Tags: visual-c++, bitmap, visual-studio-2015, transparency, direct2d

I'm trying to load a bitmap in Direct2D that already contains an alpha channel, but Direct 2D seems to always ignore the alpha channel surrounding the desired image, replacing it with opaque black. Has anyone had success with this, and could show me their code? has anyone loaded a PNG file, and convert it to a bitmap? (MSDN says it's possible, but i can't find any cases where people have had success) or is this a mask thing?
In any case, could you show me a example code snippet explaining how to do one of these things? i'm trying to make a game, i have everything else working, and this is the literal final step. if someone could show me exactly how this is done, that would make my day! just transparency in an image. that's all i need.

Comment: This question is 10 days old, but if you happen to come back, could you show a screenshot of what you're getting, and describe what you want instead?

Comment: Oh and also, what are you using to load the bitmap (WIC, GDI+, etc)?

Comment: I'm using a wic bitmap, and a converter, but after some careful detective work, I found you can use a PNG file... You just need to save the gama feature. Thanks anyway!